# C#, Object reference for nonstatic field

Tags: c#

I have COM server application which controls another application CANoe. I want to show a progress bar on Form2 of COM application. The value of progress bar should be updated in the EventHandler. The eventHandler calls a method of form2 which will update the value of progress bar. The EventHandler is in main form.

```
private void mCANoeProgProgressChangedInternal(string sysvarName, object Value) // in main Form
{
    if (mCANoeMeasurement != null && mCANoeMeasurement.Running)
    {
        ProgressBarForm.Prog_progress(Value);
    }
}
```

And in Form 2 -

```
public void Prog_progress(object value)
{
    progressBarProg.Value = (int)value;
}
```

it is showing an error

> "An object reference required for the non-static field, method or
>   property 'Form2.Prog_progress(object)'"
>   at - ProgressBarForm.Prog_progress(Value); in main form.

Please provide your comments.

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Before posting a question here you are encouraged to do a thorough research. The error message is pretty clear in the first place. In case of any further questions after that, I'm sure a simple search with a search engine of your choice would have produced the answer quicker than writing your question.

Comment: ProgressBarFrom is a class name of form2.

Answer (score 1):

In form 1 you need to execute `Prog_progress` method on an instance of Form2, not on the class (in a static way).

In Form1:

```
private ProgressBarForm _progressForm = new ProgressBarForm();
(...)
private void mCANoeProgProgressChangedInternal(string sysvarName, object Value) // in main Form
{
     if (mCANoeMeasurement != null && mCANoeMeasurement.Running)
     {
         _progressForm.Prog_progress(Value);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing instantiating the Form2,

// This is for your parent Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    private void mCANoeProgProgressChangedInternal(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarForm frm = new ProgressBarForm(); 
        frm.DoSomething(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiating a new form every time something changed would lead you to swamping your memory with unnecessary, duplicated objects.

Comment: Agreed. Better to use singleton pattern perhaps to keep it checked

Comment: Singleton might be too much, field or property in the parent class would be sufficient. Nevertheless, living object is needed :)